# Is it bad to put @Service/@Component along with @Bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Suppose I have this service bean:

```
@Service
public class MyService{
     private final HashMap<String,String> values;
       ...
}
```

with the values being:

```
com.foo:
 values:
   a: world
   b: helo
```

I may want to create it inside of a configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="com.foo")
public class MyConf{

      private Map<String, String> values;

      @Bean
      public MyService myService(){
            return new MyService(values);
      }

}
```

But I fear that spring could do something strange like creating 2 beans or dunno what...is this a good practice or should I just move @ConfigurationProperties inside of the @Service itself?

Comment: Why would you want to create the MyService Bean yourself and not let Spring Boot scan it and manage it for you ?

Comment: Because I don't know how to inject that values map inside of the service bean without having to create a specific class :(

Comment: Use Service annotation with componentscan and instead of using ConfigurationProperties, use the Value annotation to inject the properties from the environment

Answer (score 1):

You can inject your configuration directly into your Service

```
@Service
public class MyService{
     private final MyConf conf; 

     public MyService(MyConf conf) {
         this.conf = conf;
     }
}
```

And remove the @Bean annotation from MyConf allong with myservice method.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that, as it will create two beans of the same type.

In your case, you have not mentioned different names for the beans
so it will override if `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` else it will fail.

PS: For `@Service` annotation to create a bean, the class package should be configured in the `@ComponentScan` or in the base scan package

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use your properties values in your Service class (or anywhere else) you should just inject it :

```
@Service
public class MyService{
     @Autowired
     private MyConf myConf;
}
```